# Why are the "author" entries for commits in my "git log" output different from the user I am logged into Heroku as when I made the commit?

Tags: git, heroku

I inherited a Heroku project and am still a little confused about the relationship between Heroku and Git.  As I understand it, Heroku uses Git "behind the scenes" for source control.

I logged into Heroku (via Heroku login) and cloned a repository:

```
git clone https://git.heroku.com/my-repo.git
```

Then I made a trivial change to a file, added the file, and commited:

```
git add myfile
git commit myfile -m "trivial change"
```

But then if I run git log, my commit is associated with a different username (an old email address that I believe I created when was installing Git Bash for Windows).

My main question here is where is that other email address coming from?  In other words, **in what situation would the following occur?** (step #6 is what I'm concerned about)

1. heroku login with aaa@bbb.com
2. heroku whoami returns aaa@bbb.com
3. In the "Access" tab for the app in the Heroku web page, the only username that has access is aaa@bbb.com (plus another real developer)
4. git remote -v returns origin  https://git.heroku.com/my-repo.git
5. edit file and git commit
6. **git log has entries where Author: some-other-email-address@foo.com**
7. my _netrc file has the following (no reference to the other email address):

> ```
> machine code.heroku.com
> machine api.heroku.com
>   login aaa@bbb.com
>   password <XXXXX>
> machine git.heroku.com
>   login aaa@bbb.com
>   password <XXXXX>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration for git is located under your home directory : `~/.git/config`

You can change the username and email with these commands (which are going to change the .git/config file) :

```
git config --global user.name 'Your Name'
git config --global user.email '<your_email>'
```

Comment: Ah - got it.  And yes, the config file matched what I saw in git log.  So to be clear, I can put anything I like here?  Is there any relationship to the heroku login?  Or is there any way that for a given change, I can see which heroku user made it?

Comment: @Jer, normally, Git initializes these fields with your current logged in username and create an email address based on your username and the server name. Each user can change this configuration, so they can choose what username and email address that will appear in their commits. You can establish a convention with the developers as to which username and email to use. As the project admin, you can also setup code reviewing, if it is not already done, to make sure the convention is respected, so you can always see who made what changes.